# Why having a good uv map is important?

Tags: uv

I just did a painting test in substance painter with a really dirty light mass UV map, and the bake is good, the paint leave no artifacts, normal map and height painting is also good.

So I’m wondering why is it really necessary to have the regular clean uv map and in which case they are really important ? [image]

Comment: It is possible that it stretches your textures at some point when you don't have a clean UV map!

Comment: Animation (deformation of the mesh) & Photorealism (stretching can be an issue when painting accurate textures).

Comment: IMO _"good"_ needs to be clarified here. Yep your UV looks good. Would call that a "texture atlas" or "decal sheet"  as opposed to having a net that appears to share edges, and could be "folded" back into the shape.  The question then being _When to prefer one over the other?_

Comment: Could someone elaborate on why this type of uv map is a problem with deformation ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my answer I will only cover the importance of good UV layouts for real-time graphics engines, because it's the only topic I have enough experience in to write about.

**Importance in Real-time Graphics Engines**
Besides giving artists the advantage to hand-paint models, good UV maps are very important for any type of real-time graphics engine (the likes you'll find in any modern game engine). The reason for this is obviously performance.

**Enter the wonderful World of Draw Calls:**
Simply put, every time a graphics engine needs to draw an object with a texture-based material (one or multiple textures) on the screen, it sends a message to the CPU to load the object mesh data and the material from the storage medium (conventional hard disk, ssd, DVD,...).

The CPU then sends the data block to the already waiting GPU, which processes the data block into a visual representation on the screen.

If you dive further into the matter, you soon find out, that every UV island has seams that produce another draw call per seam, while the GPU figures out how to stitch the islands together.

Every draw call produces load on CPU, GPU, RAM, VRAM and the storage medium. If you have loads of them, the frame rate will suffer.

**Conclusion** 
Again, in highly simplified terms, you get the amount of draw calls per object by adding up the materials and the texture islands on the UV map.

This is the reason why game asset artists try to use every trick in the book to use the maximal available texture space while maintaining a the lowest amount of UV islands.

**Further Information on Draw Calls**
[Simon Scheibt's Render Hell](https://simonschreibt.de/gat/renderhell/) delivers the most complete source on the topic that I know of.

Comment: Thanks for tor answer !

Comment: Im curious to hear why thoses maps are bad in other domains too

Comment: Do you have a source for your draw call claim?  I don't believe this is correct.  Check out the reply at https://polycount.com/discussion/85675/uv-unwrapping-best-practice-factors-priorities

Comment: @Nathan - other than my own experience and finding the answer to my problem somewhere in Simonschreibt's Render Hell, no. But then there are also not really many other sources that substantiate the claim on polycount.

Comment: @Nathan - then again, after reading the polycount post more closely, he writes "UV seams do not cause drawcalls. When the model uses more than one material... this is what causes additional draw calls." and yet in the next paragraph "Edit... a draw call is when the game engine has to send a new set of vertices to the graphics card, to be rendered. [..]" The next one says "UV seams do increase the number of vertices for the model. But it's really not that big of a deal, unless you have something aberrant, like every quad is a separate island." Quite a bit of contradicting stuff, if you ask me.

Comment: @metaphor_set It's consistent.  A draw call sets rendering *parameters* for a specific set of vertices.  So long as those parameters stay constant (same mat, same transforms), you can do it all in a single draw call.  The vertices themselves are doubled in cases of split normals, split UV, different materials, but split normals and split UV are just per-vertex data that can be sent without changing rendering params.  Think about atlasing: if islands were draw calls, there'd be no benefit to texture atlases.